# how to use multiple DB connections in python unit test

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I need to use multiple connections in my python test code. But the problem I'm facing is that the second connection does not see statements executed in the first one. As far as I understand autocommit should be ON by default.

Here is the code

```
import testing.postgresql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


def test_simple():

with testing.postgresql.Postgresql() as postgresql:
    try:
        engine = create_engine(postgresql.url())
        conn = engine.connect().connection

        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE country (id integer, name text);
            INSERT INTO country(id, name) VALUES (1, 'Mali');
            INSERT INTO country(id, name) VALUES (2, 'Congo');
            """)

            # OK
            cur.execute('select * from country')
            countries = cur.fetchall()
            print(str(countries))

        # ERROR psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "country" does not exist
        conn1 = engine.connect().connection
        with conn1.cursor() as cur1:
            cur1.execute('select * from country')
            countries1 = cur1.fetchall()
            print(str(countries1))

    finally:
        conn.close()
        conn1.close()
```

How can I use multiple connections in my test?

Comment: Why do you use [the raw DB-API connection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.connection) instead of the one provided by sqlalchemy?

Comment: @Nils Werner I cannot answer right now. This is code which I need to maintain. Probably it was written that way to call stored procedures or something.

Comment: @Nils Werner your suggestion about using normal connection solved my issue. Thanks a lot ! You may write it as an answer and I'll accept it.